# How do I customize variables to prevent overwriting styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, react-bootstrap

I've been investigating alternative ways to include Bootstrap easily to my project and I'm not pleased with the solution. Options:

**1. react-bootstrap**

just use the components imported in JSX >> override styles of it (yuck!)

**2. bootstrap-loader (https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader)**

parameterize the styles but write the components in HTML (yuck!)

**3. Can I have both?**

How do I write bootstrap components in JSX but get those basic bootstrap variables customized so I can avoid things such as overwriting styles in basic bootstrap navbar?

Comment: Here's the deprecated version of the solution, can I achieve this with something that's not deprecated: https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader

Comment: I'm new in React.js so forgive me this question: why you don't just include `bootstrap.min.js` and `boostrap.min.css` in `<head`> in your `index.html` template and then just use bootsrtap classes around react components?

Comment: Could you explain the problem with react-bootstrap a bit?
What about using sass-loader and requiring the styles in the entry file?

Comment: I want a highly customized bootstrap without overriding too much of the styles, but set them in variables instead.

@Herku: in react-bootstrap I am unable to set the custom variables.

Please provide me some example if you find one?

Answer (score 0):

React Bootstrap does not [ship with styles](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html). You will have to insert your own styles. However React Bootstrap is not dependent on jQuery.

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN.

But you don't have to use a prebuild version of the styles (like from the download or a CDN). You can use the [customizer from the website](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) or compile the files yourself with Less or Sass. Before compiling edit the variables in the variables file.

Depending on your setup you can use a loader for your files. Webpack example:

```
// es5
require('less!./path/to/style.less');

// es2015 modules
import 'less!./path/to/style.less';
```

Or register the loader in your webpack config and you can get rid of the `less!`prefix.

Hope this helps you, feel free to ask.